# ASP.NET Core 2.2: web.config and deployment to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

**Big Edits**

I have a C# ASP.Net core 2.2 (was 2.1 in original question) web app that I am trying to deploy to an IIS 8.5 server. The deployment happens.  I can reach the default route and the server side actions work for that route.  None of the other defined routes work though.  On the IIS Server, If I try for an `MyInitialController` action other than `Index` I get the error page:

```
    HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
    The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

    Detailed Error Information:
    Module     IIS Web Core
    Notification       BeginRequest
    Handler    Not yet determined
    Error Code     0x80070003
    Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
    Config File    \\?\E:\www\myapp.company.com\Content\MyInitialController\web.config
    Requested URL      https://myapp.company.com:443/MyInitialController/Item?device=MY_WIDGET
    Physical Path      E:\www\myapp.company.com\Content\MyInitialController\Calendar
    Logon Method       Not yet determined
    Logon User     Not yet determined

    Config Source:
       -1: 
        0: 

    More Information:
    This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.
    View more information »
```

Note the value of `Config File`. On the IIS server there is no folder named: "MyInitialController". The "root" of the IIS site folder is: \?\E:\www\myapp.company.com\Content. I have no idea what is causing it to think that the web.config should be one level down in a folder that does not exist.

`startup.cs`:

```
using System;
using CalendarMyInitialControllers.Models.Commodities;
using CalendarMyInitialControllers.Models.UserTracking;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace CalendarMyInitialControllers {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            // Add memory cache services
            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600); //You can set Time   
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/MyInitialController/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "default",
                    "{controller=MyInitialController}/{action=Index}"
                );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "Calendar",
                    "MyInitialController/Item/{device}"
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

launchSettings:

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52839",
            "sslPort": 44375
        }
    },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44375;http://localhost:5000",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    },
    "CalendarReservations": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44375;http://localhost:5000",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

appSettings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report to reveal more information. You might paste the report as part of the question, so that others can comment on what might be wrong.

Comment: Will look at doing that tomorrow.  Had no idea such a thing existed

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure to read the [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). As the guide says in the beginning, make sure you have the hosting bundle installed.

In the guide, it mentions you will need a `web.config` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#webconfig-file).

There is a more detailed guide for `web.config` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuration-with-webconfig).

When I publish through Visual Studio, one is created for me. If that doesn't happen for you, you can always manually add a web.config at the root of your project. In fact, that's usually a better approach.

A basic example of a `web.config` would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the unexpected `MyInitialController` dir issue.  The IIS Server Admin created the "Base Settings" -> "Base Path" string as `...myapp.company.com\Content\MyInitialController`.  I removed the trailing `MyInitialController` and restarted the site.  I now have other issues but this one is closed.